# Why is there in a nop in the while loop

Tags: disassembly

So I have the following C code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int i = 1;

    while(i) {
        printf("in loop\n");
        i++;

        if(i == 10) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2 it disassembles to this:

```
   0x000000000040051c <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x000000000040051d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400520 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000400524 <+8>: movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040052b <+15>:    jmp    0x400541 <main+37>
   0x000000000040052d <+17>:    mov    $0x400604,%edi
   0x0000000000400532 <+22>:    callq  0x4003f0 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400537 <+27>:    addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053b <+31>:    cmpl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053f <+35>:    je     0x400549 <main+45>
   0x0000000000400541 <+37>:    cmpl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400545 <+41>:    jne    0x40052d <main+17>
   0x0000000000400547 <+43>:    jmp    0x40054a <main+46>
   0x0000000000400549 <+45>:    nop
   0x000000000040054a <+46>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000040054f <+51>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400550 <+52>:    retq
```

Why is there a `nop` on +45? And why does not `je` on +35 just jump right to +46?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be for function alignment. As it is now it returns on `0x400550`, which can be divided by 8. If it returned on `0x40054f` it isn't aligned. Just a speculation, though.

Comment: I Googled function alignment and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912464/why-does-gcc-pad-functions-with-nops) post on SO, and it seems to answer my question in some more detail. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not convinced this is *function* alignment. This only applies to function starts, not ends. It's not `-falign-labels` either (there is a `nop` inserted as per [description of `falign-labels`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) but the adjusted address is not used). I rather think this is caused by the compiler reserving some bytes for longer representation of opcodes and not cleaned up.

Comment: Yes, this just appears to be unoptimized code. Try comparing the code generated by `-O3` or `-Os` to the code generated by `-O0`.

Answer (score 3):

> Most microprocessors fetch code in aligned 16-byte or 32-byte blocks.
>   If an important subroutine entry or jump label happens to be near the
>   end of a 16-byte block then the microprocessor will only get a few
>   useful bytes of code when fetching that block of code. It may have to
>   fetch the next 16 bytes too before it can decode the first
>   instructions after the label. This can be avoided by aligning
>   important subroutine entries and loop entries by 16. Aligning by 8
>   will assure that at least 8 bytes of code can be loaded with the first
>   instruction fetch, which may be sufficient if the instructions are
>   small.

via Optimizing subroutines in assembly language by Agner Fog. [PDF](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf)

Comment: Can you point out this better alignment in the OP's disassembly? I don't get why the `nop`s place would be an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for NOP insertion is due to pipeline scheduling. If it takes a cycle for branch prediction to determine whether it was correct or not (and if not to flush the pipe), then you'd need a cycle delay before results are committed to registers.

Regarding the specific example where the jump equal goes to a NOP, it appears to me that the processor needs a cycle to determine whether it got the right answer or not and adjust the pipe as necessary.

Great job digging in to the code and understanding what is going on. :)